# How can I make my menu RESPONSIVE?

Tags: html, css

I created a pop menu here: https://jsfiddle.net/8f3vLh0a/1/

I tried to tweak things to formulate a perfect one but wondering how can I make it responsive. So that when you resize it it will look good on smaller devices.

here's my css:

```
.icon-box.home h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #E74C3C; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
        border-left: 3px solid #a7382d;

}

.icon-box.home a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.aboutme h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #1dd0ad; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #0d866e;
}

.icon-box.aboutme a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.portfolio h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #3498db; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #2177b1;
}

.icon-box.portfolio a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.blog h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #f1c40f; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #b8960e;
}

.icon-box.blog a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.contact h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #f39c12; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #bc780d;
}

.icon-box.contact a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}





span.icon { display: inline-block; background: url('../img/icon-sprites.png')no-repeat;  width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 43px 40px;}
span.icon.home { background-position: 0px 0px;}
span.icon.aboutme { background-position: -36px 0px;}
span.icon.portfolio { background-position: -72px 0px;}
span.icon.blog { background-position: -109px 0px;}
span.icon.contact { background-position: -145px 0px;}

.icon-box a {
    padding: 120px;
}
```

ANY IDEA how to make it RESPONSIVE on all browser?

JSFIDDLE PLEASE?

NOTE: NO BOOTSTRAP PLEASE

Comment: you can use **bootstrap** which is best but if you don't want that then you can use `@Media` queries

Comment: how can use media queries? No bootstrap please.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good fit for stack overflow. There are many different ways to do it. You have to try one way, if it doesn't work, then you have a good question for stack overflow

Comment: try to set `<meta name="responsive" value="true">` in your head element.

Comment: On a side note, you should combine all common css into one block.  You have duplicate css attributes for all of the ```.icon-box``` classes.  You should have something like ```.icon-box.contact, .icon-box.home```... etc. and then the common css

Answer (score 1):

use `@Media` queries

[Media Queries CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

or better  use `Bootstrap`

[Bootstrap Grid Layout](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) for responsiveness

Comment: I would say "faster" instead of "better" for bootstrap. Native knowledge allow you to build more things, and offer more flexibility

Comment: @Apolo Perhaps he means that Bootstrap is better for creating more readable code - though you aren't wrong.

Comment: I personally don't like the bootstrap semantic, I find the classes (like `col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1`) more harmful for readability. I prefer using flex and media queries. There is an excellent answer on SO about all the layouts you can achieve with flex only : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3484498

Comment: Another good article about how to make a powerful grid system from scratch without bootstrap : http://codepen.io/TBernard/post/an-awesome-grid

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

> The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.
>
> In CSS2 this was called media types, while in CSS3 it is called media queries.
>
> Media queries look at the capability of the device, and can be used to check many things, such as:
>
> width and height of the viewport
> width and height of the device
> orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
> resolution
> and much more

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your site from scratch the correct CSS tool you will need is [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), which are not complicated themselves.

Below is an example of a media query that refers to the iPhone 6, although it is not necessary to write a query for every device that visits your site, this may give you an idea of what the syntax looks like - you would add CSS rules inside the curly brackets.

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

If you would like to use a framework, there are many options: Bootstrap, Foundation, Toast Grid, Skeleton CSS, etc. Bootstrap is the most overwhelmingly popular, but Foundation is also very well know and widely used.